# Programmatically check a checkbox using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, coffeescript

How can I programmatically check a checkbox in Coffeescript ?

I know in Javascript, I can use this :

```
myElement.checked = true
```

Can I do something like the following in Coffeescript ?

```
myElement.checked "true"
```

I have already tried the above but it isn't working for me.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `myElement` a checkbox? I suspect something else is wrong. You could post some relevant code. Eg: When are you trying to call this? How are you selecting `myElement` etc.

Comment: If `myElement.checked = true` works in JavaScript then `myElement.checked = true` should also work in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Yes, `myElement` is a checkbox. I am selecting it using it's ID. Also, `myElement.disable "true"` is disabling the checkbox absolutely fine in CoffeeScript. And so it seems there's no problem with the selection of the element.

Comment: @muistooshort: You're right, `myElement.checked = "yes"` works perfectly in plain javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
myElement.checked = "yes";

myElement.checked = null;// for unchecking
```

So, for [your case](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/myZwM/1/),

`a.checked = b.checked; //i.e. check a if b is checked`

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/D9N87/1/)

---

```
//CoffeeScript
a = {}
a.b = 10
alert a.b
```

Compiles to..

```
//javascript
var a;
a = {};
a.b = 10;
alert(a.b);
```

**However**, `a.b 10` compiles to `a.b(10)` in javascript, which is not what you want. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robin. But I have tried `myElement.checked = true`, and it didn't work either. Also, just to add to the info ... `myElement.disable "true"` works absolutely fine for disabling the same checkbox.

Comment: @Myxtic: Then try `checked = "yes"`. I think that's the right way in plain javascript.

Comment: That didn't work either, weird. So what I tried was : `$('#my_element_id').checked = "yes"` ... that should have worked, right ? Also, just for clarification, once again, when I do `$('#my_element_id').disable "true"` it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for the example Robin. But it still doesn't work :( No idea why ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myZwM/ -- I want to mark checkbox 'a' as checked, if checkbox 'b' is checked.

Comment: @Myxtic: Then just do `a.checked = b.checked` :) [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/myZwM/1/)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the logic would work. But I guess the problem is that `.checked` syntax is not working for me in CoffeeScript.

Comment: @Myxtic: Did you visit the link in my previous comment?

Comment: Ok so it finally worked. The problem was with the way I was referencing the element - `$('#my_element_id')` - as soon as I changed that to - `document.getElementById('my_element_id')` - it began to work. No idea why that happened. But atleast that solved it for now. Thanks so much for all your help !

Comment: @Myxtic: Glad to help. Note, while wrapping with a jQuery object, you need to do `jQElem.attr('checked')` or access the plain element by doing `jQElem[0].checked`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `myElement` is jQuery object and you want to address DOM element:

```
// HTML
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox"/>


//coffeescript

$('.toggle')[0].checked = true
```