# toggle checkboxes selected and unselected ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, toggle

I have a code here in cofeescript to make a select all function in my list:
in my view:

= submit_tag "Check All", :onclick => "checkUncheckAll(this, message_ids[])"

js.cofee:

toggle = (source) ->
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("user_message_ids[]")
  for i of checkboxes
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked

Comment: What is the question here? Can you explain more?

Comment: I just want to know how to make a select all function, this one is not  working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `button_tag` instead of `submit_tag`. Because `submit_tag` adds a `type="submit"` which is actually submit the form.

Secondly, This might help you to handle your checkboxes by cofeescript [ [Programmatically check a checkbox using CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981577/programmatically-check-a-checkbox-using-coffeescript) ]